# lamp stack localhost using vagrant - not getting any error messages in var/log for system.log or exception.log

Tags: magento-enterprise, log, exception, apache

It's a magento 12 ee build... I went into some core code and purposely changed a method for log exception purposes to see if i would throw and error. It broke my store (like i suspected) and i got the error message on the front end but it's not writing to my log.

```
System => Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64
Build Date => Apr 17 2015 15:09:58
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/00-ioncube.ini,
```

I just finished checking the permissions on the log folder and it's set to 755.

It's turned on = yes in system preferences of the admin panel.

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '12',
            'revision'  => '0',
            'patch'     => '2',
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit index.php in magento root folder and find //error_reporting(0) and replace with error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); and refresh the page. It should display the error.
2. Check php error logs. It should be usually under i/var/log/apache2. Fatal errors will be reported there.